# Angular - edit a BehaviorSubject Array

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm sending a request to the server to modify one of the users.

As a response, the server sends back the updated user.

After that I'm trying to update the BehaviorSubject of all the users like this:

```
   private currentHeroes = new BehaviorSubject<Hero[]>(null);
   currentHeroes$ = this.currentHeroes.asObservable();


 powerUp(id: number) {
return this.http
  .post<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {})
  .pipe(
    tap((updatedHero: Hero) => {
      this.currentHeroes.next(
        this.currentHeroes.value.map((hero: Hero) =>
          hero.id === updatedHero.id ? updatedHero : hero
        ).sort(a=>a.currentPower)
      );
    })
  );
```

}

**In case of deleting:**

```
    delete(id: number) {
return this.http.delete<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/' + id).pipe(
  tap((deletedHero: Hero) => {
    this.currentHeroes.value.filter(
      (hero: Hero) => hero.id !== deletedHero.id
    );
  })
);
```

}

I'm trying to modify the array of users. Replace the old user with the updated user.

And the code doesn't reach the pipe of the currentHeroes$.
I'm not really sure why is that happening or how can I fix it.

I have tried to return a value from the pipe or use tap instead of map but no luck.

Does any can maybe take a look to explain to me why does it happen? or how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Updating an object in array

##### Variant 1: Using `value` getter of `BehaviorSubject`

You don't have to `pipe` to the `BehaviorSubject`. You'd just need to use the [`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) operator on the source observable (HTTP request) and update the `BehaviorSubject` in it's callback. `tap` operator is akin to `map` but wouldn't transform the incoming emissions. So it's ideal for performing side-effects like updating a local variable.

```js
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

powerUp(id: number) {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {}).pipe(
    tap((updatedHero: any) => {
        this.currentHeroes.next(
          this.currenHeroes.value.map((hero: Hero) =>        // <-- `Array#map` function
            hero.id === updatedHero.id ? updatedHero : hero
          )
        );
      }
    })
  );
}
```

##### Variant 2: Using `withLatestFrom` operator

If you do not wish to use the [`value`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.1.0/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L16) getter from the `BehaviorSubject`, you could try to use the [`withLatestFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom) operator to fetch it's latest value.

```js
import { tap, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

powerUp(id: number) {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {}).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.currentHeroes$),
    tap(([updatedHero, currentHeroes]) => {
        this.currentHeroes.next(
          currenHeroes.map((hero: Hero) => 
            hero.id === updatedHero.id ? updatedHero : hero
          )
        );
      }
    })
  );
}
```

---

#### Deleting an object in array

As mentioned in the comments, to delete an element in the array, you could use the `Array#filter` instead of `Array#map` function.

##### Variant 1: Using `value` getter of `BehaviorSubject`

```js
import { tap, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

powerUp(id: number) {
  return this.http.delete<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/' + id).pipe(
    tap(([deletedHero, currentHeroes]) => {
        this.currentHeroes.next(
          this.currentHeroes.value.filter((hero: Hero) => hero.id !== deletedHero.id)
        );
      }
    })
  );
}
```

##### Variant 2: Using `withLatestFrom` operator

```js
import { tap, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

powerUp(id: number) {
  return this.http.delete<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/' + id).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.currentHeroes$),
    tap(([deletedHero, currentHeroes]) => {
        this.currentHeroes.next(
          currentHeroes.filter((hero: Hero) => hero.id !== deletedHero.id)
        );
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: But actually i have another question. Thanks to you I understood my mistake! But in case of deleting a hero. ----> hero.id === deletedHero.id ? {} : hero;        doesn't work.  did I miss anything? because just {} doesn't work as I thought it would

Comment: I have edited my qeustion so you can see how can I try to delete a hero

Comment: No in that case you'd have an empty object in the array. For removing the object, you could use `Array#filter`: `currenHeroes.filter((hero: Hero) => hero.id !== deletedHero.id)`.

Comment: unfortently i have tried and it says : Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<Hero[]>'.ts(2339)

Comment: Yes because this is the 2nd variant of the answer. For this to work you'd need to use `withLatestFrom` operator. Or you could just use the `value` getter: `this.currentHeroes.value.filter((hero: Hero) => hero.id !== deletedHero.id)`

Comment: yeah. btw i have added the delete method so you can see. I don't really understand why it doesn't work. (The second method works but I really want to understand how to make the first one work as well)

Comment: @David: I've updated the answer for updating and deleting elements from array using both the variants. To understand why your solution didn't, I'd recommend reading up on the `value` getter of the `BehaviorSubject` and the RxJS `withLatestFrom` operator.

Comment: Thanks!
One last question please, Could you please explain to me in a few words what does withLatestFrom do? As i understand it takes the latest value from the BehaviorSubject. right ?

Comment: @David: Yes exactly and not just `BehaviorSubject`. It could take the latest value from any observable and include it in the emission stream as an additional element to an array. We were obtaining these elements using the spread syntax `([deletedHero, currentHeroes])`. The first element is the emission from the HTTP request, the second is the emission from the `withLatestFrom` operator.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for the amazing explanation!!!

Comment: Last thing, is it possible to apply few filters together? I mean to sort by integer?

Comment: I tried to use the .sort() after the map but with no success. i Have edited the question could you please take a look?

Comment: @David: You're using the `Array#sort` function wrong. It must be `.sort((a,b) => (a.currentPower > b.currentPower) ? 1 : ((b.currentPower > a.currentPower) ? -1 : 0))`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/6513921

Comment: Generally speaking, its possible to make few operations on .value()? Lets say .map() and after it .sort() ect?

Comment: @David: If the value held by the `BehaviorSubject` is an array, then yes.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Sorry for asking this question so late. Is it possible to apply this logic to a Subject and not BehaviorSubject